# How to link and sum columns

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a workbook with two columns, A and B. Column A contain different names and Column B contains integers. Column B has no link or merging that connects cells to each other.

It can look as follow:

```
Dog      500

Cat      500

Total      1000

Apple    300

Pear     300

Orange   300

Total     900
```

In column A, we have Dog and Cat with two different sums that together will be the total. They are not connected to each other.

Is there any code that can run through the columns and for every "Total" it finds it connects the rows above total?

Like the code runs through, finds TOTAL, and understands that DOG + CAT = TOTAL, so whenever CAT or DOG are edited Total will change.

Comment: Is the total just hardcoded in?  For example, 1,000 or 900?  What have you tried so far?  Stack Overflow is not really about asking people to do your work for you but rather to answer questions that will help others solve their problems.

Comment: Are you saying the word "Total" is already in there and you just need to sum all above data until it hits another "Total" cell?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub t()
    nextGroupStartRow = 1
    For i = 1 To Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row
        If Range("A" & i).Value = "Total" Then
            Range("B" & i).Formula = "=sum(B" & i - 1 & ":B" & nextGroupStartRow & ")"
            nextGroupStartRow = i + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The VBAscript answer is nice, but if you don't feel like scripting, you can do it with formulas:

This is going to look weird, and you'll likely have to put it into your workbook to prove it to yourself, but this should work.  Assuming your file looks like you've stated, and the first "total" is on row 3, paste this formula into cell B3:

```
=sum(B$2:B1)-sumif(A$1:A3,”Total”,B$1:B3)
```

Then do a cut and paste of that cell beside every subsequent "Total" row, and it'll work.  You'll have to adjust the formula if you have a header row, or if you change columns.